# Can we union 2 RDDs by ignoring their value type in spark

Tags: apache-spark

Desired Output:

```
Array((h, (None, Some(12))), (a, (Some(2), None)), (b,(Some(5), None)), 
      (c, (Some(4), None)), (d, (Some(12), None)), (e,  (None, Some(2))),
      (f, (None, Some(5))), (g, (None, Some(4))))
```

Code:

```
val a = sc.parallelize(List(("a",2),("b",5),("c",4),("d",12)))

val b = sc.parallelize(List(("e",2),("f",5),("g",4),("h",12)))

val c = a.map{case(k,v) => (k) -> (Some(v),None)}

val d = b.map{case(k,v) => (k) -> (None,Some(v))}

val e = c.union(d)
```

while doing c.union(d) i am getting the type mismatch error.
Can some one please help, is the approach of solving this problem correct or i need to take some other approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that since you are not specifying the type of the elements in the RDD, scala tries to infer them, and uses `Type.none` which in the union is different from both `Some[Int]` and `Some[String]`.

For union to work, you have to make sure the data has the same types. One way to do it is making sure everything is `Option[Any]`:

```
scala> val d = b.map{case(k,v) => (k) -> ( 
None.asInstanceOf[Option[Any]],Some(v).asInstanceOf[Option[Any]])}
d: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Option[Any], Option[Any]))] = 
MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at <console>:26

scala> val c = a.map{case(k,v) => (k) -> 
  (Some(v).asInstanceOf[Option[Any]],None.asInstanceOf[Option[Any]])}
c: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Option[Any], Option[Any]))] = 
MapPartitionsRDD[6] at map at <console>:26

scala> c.union(d)
res1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Option[Any], Option[Any]))] = 
UnionRDD[7] at union at <console>:33
```

Answer (score 1):

Just annotate the types:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

type T = (String, (Option[Int], Option[Int]))

val c: RDD[T] = a.map{ case(k, v) => (k, (Some(v), None)) }
val d: RDD[T] = b.map{ case(k, v) => (k, (None, Some(v))) }

c.union(d)
```